# sqlite database not printing the contents of the database

Tags: python, sqlite, python-2.7

```
createDataBase1 = sqlite3.connect('PythonDatabase_1.db')
queryCurs1 = createDataBase1.cursor()
def createtable():
    queryCurs1.execute("""CREATE TABLE Scores
    (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Name TEXT, Class TEXT, Score INTERGER)""")

def addPupil1(Name, Class, Score):
    queryCurs1.execute("""INSERT INTO Scores (Name, Class, Score)
    VALUES(?,?,?)""",(Name, Class, Score,))

def main1():
    createtable1()
    addPupil1
    (Name, Class, Score)
    createDataBase1.commit()

    queryCurs1.execute("SELECT * FROM Scores ORDER BY Score DESC")

    title = ["id","Name", "Class", "Score"]
    k = 0
    for i in queryCurs1:
        print "\n"
        for j in i:
            print title[k],
            print j
            if k < 3: k += 1
            else: k = 0

    queryCurs1.close()
    if __name__ == '__main__':main()
```

This used to print out the results now it doesn't what is wrong?
it used to display the results in a list format with the titles in front now it doesn't what is wrong

Comment: A lot of undefined variables, `Name, Class, Score,k`

Comment: are `main()` and `main1()` meant to be different functions? If so could you show us where  `main()` is defined and where `main1()` is called.

Comment: no they are meant to be the same

Comment: @RonanCohen in that case I'm assuming that the `if __name__` should not be indented to be within the `main()` function

Comment: i just tried it and the same, nothing

Comment: Is `createtable1()` different from `createtable()` ?

Comment: What error do you get? Please update your question with the exact traceback. Also be sure that the code you present is exactly the same as you use.

Answer (score 0):

I took the liberty of changing your code. Check if it works for you. I prefer using [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for code style. Also I inserted a generic record to the database (change it to whatever you need).

On the other hand, I also changed the create statement of your table, because once the table is created (running a command twice) it displays an error because the table is already created.

The code looks like this:

```
import sqlite3

created_db = sqlite3.connect('PythonDatabase_1.db')
cursor = created_db.cursor()

def create_table():
    cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Scores
    (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Name TEXT, Class TEXT, Score INTERGER)""")

def add_pupil(name, klass, score):
    cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO Scores (Name, Class, Score)
    VALUES(?,?,?)""",(name, klass, score,))

def main():
    create_table()

    name = "John Doe"
    klass = "Math"
    score = 100

    add_pupil(name, klass, score)
    created_db.commit()

    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Scores ORDER BY Score DESC")

    title = ["id","Name", "Class", "Score"]
    k = 0

    for i in cursor:
        print "\n"
        for j in i:
            print title[k],
            print j
            if k < 3: k += 1
            else: k = 0

    cursor.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Hope it helps,